# Is it possible to install and run two versions of Dreamweaver, older and newer?

Tags: dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I use DW `CS5` and would like to test `CS5.5` without uninstalling `CS5`. Can both be installed on one computer and run either together at the same time or separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both installed at the same time. On Mac you can run both at the same time, on Windows, you can run one or the other, but both at the same time.